# How to express cotangent using Euler's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The problems states

Express $cot (\theta)$ using $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$

I interpreted the $e^{i\theta}$ as $e^{i\theta} = cos (\theta) + i sin(\theta)$
and $e^{-i\theta} = cos ({-\theta})+isin({-\theta})$

However, I am stuck what to do next, step by step help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: do it the other way around: $\sin \theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i \theta}}{2i}$ and something similar for $\cos$

Comment: Sam333. Try to solve these two simultaneous equations with respect to $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4383406/show-that-frac1z1-z-i-cot-frac-theta2/4734088#4734088

Answer (score 1):

For the solution of the two equations, consider the fact that $\cos(-\theta) = \cos{\theta}$ and $\sin{(-\theta)} = -\sin{\theta}$. Therefore, the equation for $e^{-i\theta}$ can be written as $e^{-i\theta} = \cos{\theta} - i\sin{\theta}$.  Subtracting $e^{-i\theta} = \cos{\theta} - i\sin{\theta}$ from $e^{i\theta} = \cos{\theta} + i\sin{\theta}$ yields $$2i\sin{\theta} = e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta} \implies \sin{\theta} = \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}.$$ Adding the two equations,
$$e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} = 2\cos{\theta} \implies \cos{\theta} = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}.$$
Now, knowing that $\cot{\theta} = \frac{\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}$, we get
$\cot{\theta} = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}i$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that,
$$\sin \theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i \theta}}{2i},$$

$$\cos \theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i \theta}}{2}.$$

So taking the ratio will simply lead to

$$\cot{\theta} = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}i.$$

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?